JPAqueryfactory cannot be resolved to a type i springboot While adding QueryDSL
I am trying to learn about test driven development using JUnit in springboot. When I am adding queryDSL query I am getting compile time error saying that JPAqueryfactory cannot be resolved to a type on JPA queryfactory line. And not able to run project,
My pom.xml file looks like the following,
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>
   </properties>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>    
   </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

          <plugin>
             <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
             <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

And generated Q type classes looks like following in target directory,

My controller sample code like the following,
import com.devopsauthorize.model.QUsers;
import com.devopsauthorize.model.Users;
import com.devopsauthorize.services.UserService;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;


@RequestMapping("/cicd")
@RestController
public class PipelineController {

   @Autowired
   UserService userServiceObj;

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   @GetMapping("/load")
   public String loadPipelineMessageMethod(){

    //return userServiceObj.retrieveUserRoleDetails("dmoore");
   QUsers users = QUsers.users;
   JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
   Users userObj = queryFactory.selectFrom(users)
        .where(users.susername.eq("cvo"))
        .fetchOne();

     System.out.println(userObj.susername);
      System.out.println(userObj.spassword);
      return userObj.spassword;
       // return "hello";
    }

}

Can anyone please guide me to resolve this error or suggest any alternative way of implementation if I went on wrong direction ?


You aren't importing it so how should it be found? YOu have import statements voor all the rest, not for this.
